# Hilbert Space and Riesz's Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

If the mapping $X\longrightarrow X'$ given by $ z\mapsto f$ is surjective, show that must be a Hilbert space.

Here $f(x)=<x,z>$

I understood that the application given is an isometry. So if X isn't complete X' wouldn't be either, but I don't think I've come to a conclusion.

Comment: What is "dada" and $f$ for instance?

Comment: **What** mapping are you talking about?

Comment: $f(x)=<x,z>$, forget

Answer (score 1):

The dual space X' of a normed space X is a Banach space (whether or not X is).X and X' isomorphism thus the inner product space X is also complete, X is a Hilbert space.